# How to speed up Cupy with Streams correctly?

Tags: python, cupy

I want to use cuda streams in order to speed up small calculations on the GPU. My test so far consists of the following:

```
import cupy as xp
import time
x = xp.random.randn(10003, 20000) + 1j * xp.random.randn(10003, 20000)
y = xp.zeros_like(x)

nStreams = 16
streams = [xp.cuda.stream.Stream() for ii in range(nStreams)]

f = xp.fft.fft(x[:,:200])

t = time.time()
for ii in range(int(x.shape[1]/100)):
    ss = streams[ii % nStreams]
    with ss:
        y[:,ii*200:(ii+1)*200] = xp.fft.fft(x[:,ii*200:(ii+1)*200], axis=0)

for ii,ss in enumerate(streams):
    ss.synchronize()
print(time.time()-t)

t = time.time()
for ii in range(int(x.shape[1]/100)):
    y[:,ii*200:(ii+1)*200] = xp.fft.fft(x[:,ii*200:(ii+1)*200], axis=0)
xp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()

print(time.time()-t)
```

produces

```
[user@pc snippets]$ intelpython3 strm.py
0.019365549087524414
0.018717050552368164
```

which I have trouble believing that I do everything correctly. Additionally, the situation becomes even more severe when replacing the FFT-calls with calls to `xp.sum`, which yields

```
[user@pc snippets]$ intelpython3 strm.py
0.002195596694946289
0.001004934310913086
```

What is the rationale behind cupy streams? How do I use them to my advantage?

Comment: You are running a ridiculously large number of streams. If these stream abstractions map to CUDA streams (no idea how cupy works), you want to use a few streams to pipeline operations concurrently and utilize all the capacity of the GPU on smaller taks and potentially overlap compute and data transfer, not a few hundred. That makes no sense

Comment: I edited my code snippet accordingly. Still the numbers are the same.

Comment: Replace `list` with a `tuple`  if you want to do a intineration that only reads the variable,